# Simple algebraic step in establishing estimation of variance of errors, $e_{i}$ i.e $\sigma^{2}$ for variables in linear regression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

This is something I definitely know how to do, but is slipping my mind at the moment. I'm reading through *Rice's Mathematical Statistics* and the following is the proof to establish an estimate for the errors of the independent variables of a linear regression (You can ignore the majority of the proof it is only the last line I'm stuck on):

[image]

[image]

I understand the proof of $E(||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2}) = (n-p) \sigma^{2}$$. What I'm having trouble figuring out is how the

$$s^{2} = \frac{||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2}}{(n-p)}$$

Came about, specifically what was on the other side to allow us to divide?

$$\text{?something?} = E(||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2}) = (n-p) \sigma^{2}$$

I ask because if we're taking the expectation of $E(||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2})$, then the only thing I see appearing on the other side would be:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}E(\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}})^2$$

Which to me doesn't amount to anything special. Since what I want is

$$||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2}$$
without the expectation operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for an estimator $s^2$ for $\sigma^2$ which is **unbiased** that means:

$$
E[s^2] = \sigma^2
$$

if we define $s^{2} = \frac{||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2}}{(n-p)}$ by the theorem **A** we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
E[s^{2}] &= \frac{E[||\textbf{Y} - \hat{\textbf{Y}} ||^{2}]}{(n-p)} \\
&= \frac{(n-p)}{(n-p)} \sigma^{2} = \sigma^2
\end{aligned}
$$

This proves that, in fact, $s^2$ is unbiased.

In general terms, we have a model that depends on the value of some parameter $\theta$ (in this case: $\sigma^2$; once we have $\sigma^2$ we can fit our model to the data). An unbiased estimate $\hat{\theta}$ (in this case: $s^2$) is a value *extracted from data* which represents the information that $\theta$ is supposed to show us. It represents that parameter in such a way, that in average (i.e. expected value) it's equal to our parameter, that means:
$$
\text{Bias}(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = 0 \iff E[\hat{\theta}] = \theta \left( \text{ i.e.} \iff E[s^2] = \sigma^2 \right)
$$
There's no general strategy to find $\hat{\theta}$, so we explore the model and try to find some pattern, that allows us to declare such a $\hat{\theta}$. In our case, that pattern is given by theorem **A**, because we have an expected value on one side and our parameter, namely $\sigma^2$, explicitly on the other side. Given that structure, we propose the functional form for $s^2$ given by the book.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation here. I'm also looking forward to reading your response on the other question I posted.

Comment: No problem :) I already answered the two comments you had on the other question.

Answer (score 1):

$s^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ (*i.e., its expectation equals the parameter of interest*) because
$$
\mathsf{E}s^2=\mathsf{E}\left[\frac{\|\bf{Y}-\hat{\bf{Y}}\|^2}{n-p}\right]=\frac{(n-p)\sigma^2}{n-p}=\sigma^2.
$$